# UICollectionViewController 3 colunas auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Estou criando um UICollectionViewController com 2 ou 3 colunas, quando utilizando o autolayout em alguns Devices funciona perfeitamente mas em outros não, eu não achei nada que fale como dinamizar estas colunas com objective-c.

eu achei um em swift, que tem este cálculo.

```
private let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 30.0
private let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
private let heigthAdjustment: CGFloat = 5.0

let width = (CGRectGetWidth(collectionView!.frame) - leftAndRightPaddings) / numberOfItemsPerRow
let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout  
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width + heigthAdjustment)
```

Eu não entendi nada o que este codigo está fazendo aqui embaixo

```
let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
```

com este codigo de reiderização está funcionando com Swift mas eu não posso utilizar, meus métodos e biblioteca estão em Objective-c tentei chamar alguns e funcionaram, outros nem tanto, então eu preferi continuar com o Objective-c.

valeu...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta isso.

**MyCollectionView.swift**

```
    self.collectionView.delegate = self

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self

    collectionViewLayout = CustomFlowLayout()

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout
```

**CustomFlowLayout.swift**

class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

```
override init() {

    super.init()

    setupLayout()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setupLayout()
}

override var itemSize: CGSize {
    set {

    }
    get {
        let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 3

        let itemWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView!.frame) - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns

        return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth)
    }
}

func setupLayout() {

    minimumInteritemSpacing = 1

    minimumLineSpacing = 1

    scrollDirection = .Vertical
}
```

}

Comment: valeu deu certo